# How to set session variable in Django template

Tags: python, django, http, django-views, django-templates

How to set session variable within Django template, For example:

```
<a href="{% url 'view' request.session.data.set("First data") %}">First Button</a>
<a href="{% url 'view' request.session.data.set("Second data") %}">Second Button</a>
<a href="{% url 'view' request.session.data.set("Third data") %}">Third Button</a>
```

The Reason of doing this in the template not in the view:
by clicking a certain button on the page the user should be redirected with different session data (that depends on the button being clicked)

The Reason of not doing this with GET parameters:
The data is sensitive

Comment: Why not do it in the view using POST parameters with csrf_token?

Comment: @LaCharcaSoftware Could you please post an example.